# prevent retrieving variable values from iOS apps with decomplier IDA

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, decompiler

I have read some Q&A saying that variable values can be retrieved from app's executable.
I learn that apps are encrypted with Apple's certificate.
My understanding is apps are decrypted only when it is run and place the code into memory.

I want to know whether someone can retrieve decrypted apps for misuse on un-jailbroken iPhone.
Or what about on the jailbroken phone?

Is there any way to prevent it ?

If they can, storing secret value like encryption key hard-coded in apps is not reliable method. Am I right?

Comment: you could check out Jonathan Zdziarski's [books if you want general information on this subject](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/au/1861)

Comment: Thank you...I'll research more.